# protoc-gen-go: remove type name from generated enum?

Tags: enums, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go, protobuf-go

I am generating Go code from a ProtoBuffer enumeration. The ProtoBuffer enum is properly named and cased, but the generated Go code has malformed variant names.  The Go type, "AccessTier" is prefixed to the correct variant name, such as "ACCESS_TIER_ARCHIVE".  The correct name should simply be "ACCESS_TIER_ARCHIVE".  How can I configure the ProtoBuffer tool or buf.Build to generate the properly named enum variants?

I found the following issue, but it is still open.  I am hoping that someone may have a suggestion about how to fix it.

https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/513

Thank you for your help and interest,
Mike

buf.gen.yaml:

```
version: v1
managed:
  enabled: true
  go_package_prefix:
    default: github.com/abcd/abcdapis/gen
    except:
      - buf.build/googleapis/googleapis
plugins:
  - plugin: buf.build/bufbuild/connect-go
    out: gen
    opt: paths=source_relative
    
  - plugin: buf.build/bufbuild/validate-go:v1.0.2
    out: gen
    opt:
      - paths=source_relative

  - plugin: buf.build/protocolbuffers/go
    out: gen
    opt:
      - paths=source_relative
```

ProtoBuffer enum:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package abcd.enum.v5;

enum AccessTier {
  ACCESS_TIER_UNSPECIFIED = 0;
  ACCESS_TIER_ARCHIVE = 1;
  ACCESS_TIER_COOL = 2;
  ACCESS_TIER_HOT = 3;
}
```

The generated Go code:

```
type AccessTier int32

const (
    AccessTier_ACCESS_TIER_UNSPECIFIED AccessTier = 0
    AccessTier_ACCESS_TIER_ARCHIVE     AccessTier = 1
    AccessTier_ACCESS_TIER_COOL        AccessTier = 2
    AccessTier_ACCESS_TIER_HOT         AccessTier = 3
)

// Enum value maps for AccessTier.
var (
    AccessTier_name = map[int32]string{
        0: "ACCESS_TIER_UNSPECIFIED",
        1: "ACCESS_TIER_ARCHIVE",
        2: "ACCESS_TIER_COOL",
        3: "ACCESS_TIER_HOT",
    }
    AccessTier_value = map[string]int32{
        "ACCESS_TIER_UNSPECIFIED": 0,
        "ACCESS_TIER_ARCHIVE":     1,
        "ACCESS_TIER_COOL":        2,
        "ACCESS_TIER_HOT":         3,
    }
)
```

Comment: We can debate your definition of "malformed" and "properly named" since the generated code is parseable, compiles and is usable. IIUC your issue is that you must duplicate type names (aka "stutter") which is frustrating. You've at least 3 options: 1. Submit a solution to the referenced issue;  2. Redefine the `enum` without the prefixing type name; 3. Define an alias for the `enum` in your code with a mapping to/from the protocol buffer type.